# Ag-Grid hide specifically filter join operator

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

By default filter ag-grid have 2 join operator, which are `AND` and `OR`. But I couldn't find a way to hide the `AND` operator to only show `OR` operator. Because the `AND` operator cannot use on filter date

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to know also

Answer (score 0):

Workaround by using CSS but this will apply to all columns

```
.ag-filter-condition-operator-or {
   display:none;
 }

.ag-filter-condition-operator-and {
   display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but I was able to set "OR" to be selected by default like this:

```
filterParams: {
    defaultJoinOperator: 'OR'
}
```